# Django - 'Merging' or Sorting similar objects from a queryset

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

Good day, I have a django model that represents users (node) that have a relation (edge) with other users. User A is a friend of User B and User A interacted with User B .

```
class Node(BaseInfo):    

    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank = True, null=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank = True,null=True)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)        
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    picture_url = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank = True,null =True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank = True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank = True, null=True)
    gender= models.CharField(max_length=200,blank = True, null=True)
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=2000,blank=True,null=True)         
    edges = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Edge',blank = True)
    task = models.ManyToManyField('Task',blank = True)
    location = models.ManyToManyField('Location',blank = True)
    case = models.ManyToManyField('case',blank = True)

class Edge(BaseInfo):
    source = models.ForeignKey('Node', on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="is_source")
    target = models.ForeignKey('Node', on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="is_target")

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['source','target','label'], name="unique_edge"),
        ]
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.label)
```

At this point i query the relations with:
result = Edge.objects.filter(source = User A);
The result will contain a query set with
[Edge(User A , User B , "Friends"),[Edge(User A, User B , "Interacted")]

I want to show the relations (Grouped By ? ) of User A in a template
So it says , Profile A is a **friend and has interacted** with B. Rather then having to iterate over the queryset and having 2 lines in my template :User A is friends with B , User A interacties with user B.

I already looked in aggregation functions of Django but cant get any further.
Thanks in advance for youre guidance.

Comment: It should be possible to group by source and target using values, and annotate the relations based on the label